# ¿Es posible usar valores separados por coma para insertar en una sola columna en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Revisando [la sintaxis de la documentación sobre `INSERT INTO ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), la cual a mi juicio no es del todo clara, parecería que es posible insertar una lista de valores en una misma columna.

```
{VALUES | VALUE} (value_list) [, (value_list)] ...
```

Al leer `VALUE` y luego al lado, dos posibilidades de `value_list`, parecería que es posible hacer algo como esto:

```
INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUE (685,1281,1282);
```

En la consulta, la idea es insertar tres nuevas filas en la tabla, con `id_pericopa` igual a `685` en una fila, `1281` en otra fila y `1282` en otra.

Pero la consulta da error:

> `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Y si lo escribo así también da error:

```
INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUES (685,1281,1282);
```

**¿Es posible insertar en una misma columna varias filas sin tener que usar los paréntesis para cada fila? ¿Cómo debería escribir la consulta si fuera posible?**

Me serviría poder hacerlo así en algunos contextos en que recibo a mano una lista de valores para insertar en mi tabla de forma manual.

Comment: crees te serviría tener una columna JSON y guardarlos en ese formato? y tal vez que fuera INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUE '{"data":{"val1": 685, "val2": 1281, "val3": 1282}};

Comment: @Alfredo ¿te refieres a cambiar la columna a un tipo JSON? No me interesa cambiar la estructura de la tabla, sobre todo porque es una columna que es llave foránea en otras tablas. Es sólo por una cuestión práctica de tener la consulta escrita así: `INSERT INTO tabla (columna) VALUE ( pegar, aquí, lista, de, valores, separados, por, coma );` pegando entre los paréntesis una lista de valores a insertar en diferentes filas de esa misma columna.

Comment: ah ok comprendo permiteme pensar en otra opción

Comment: Hola. A lo mejor te sirve esto:
INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUE (685),(1281),(1282);

Comment: @marco811 sí esa forma clásica me sirve. La cuestión , como explicó en la pregunta, es que quiero evitar los paréntesis de forma que pueda pegar una lista de valores e insertarlos fácilmente. Supongamos que son 20 valores, tengo que poner los 20 entre paréntesis. Yo busco una forma que me permita copiar los 20 valores solamente separados por coma y listo.

Comment: no, no se puede.. salvo que armes la lista por codigo.

Comment: Es para hacer el insert tú mismo, 'a mano'?

Comment: Es correcto @Julio.

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que la definición no sea del todo explícita al principio, pero luego en el detalle se explica bastante bien (en mí humilde opinión), específicamente en los siguientes párrafos:

> Each values list must contain exactly as many values as are to be
>   inserted per row. The following statement is invalid because it
>   contains one list of nine values, rather than three lists of three
>   values each:
>
> `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);`
>
> **VALUE** is a synonym for **VALUES** in this context. Neither implies
>   anything about the number of values lists, nor about the number of
>   values per list. Either may be used whether there is a single values
>   list or multiple lists, and regardless of the number of values per
>   list.

Por ello, en cuanto a su pregunta:

> **¿Es posible insertar en una misma columna varias filas sin tener que usar los paréntesis para cada fila?**

Considero que actualmente MySQL no da soporte a dicha sintaxis.

Una opción que puede ser útil es [13.2.6.1 INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html), pero dependerá de su caso de uso específico.

Comment: Se agradece una traducción.

Answer (score 2):

No directamente, pero podes usar una variación de ["GROUP UNCONCAT"](https://thenoyes.com/littlenoise/?p=92)

```
SET @sourceString = '685,1281,1282';
SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUES (\'',
  REPLACE(@sourceString, ',', '\'),(\''), '\')');
PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE myStmt;
```

lefidel: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a61621/1

Answer (score -1):

Como es para hacer un INSERT a mano, sugiero lo siguiente:

Crea tu INSERT de esta manera:

`INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUE (685,1281,1282);`

y despues con cualquier editor busca/reemplaza `,` por `),(`

Obviamente sólo te ahorrará tiempo en caso de insertar bastantes datos.

Answer (score -1):

Si la columna es numérica olvídate, en el caso de que sea un varchar o equivalente puedes hacer el poner lo que quieres introducir entre comillas.

`INSERT INTO liturgia_biblicas (id_pericopa) VALUES ("685,1281,1282");`

En todo caso podrías valorar el crear otra tabla para relacionar los valores, mucho más práctico a nivel de mantenimiento